# Saving images with more than 8 bits per pixel in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to save a set of pre-processing images in matlab, resulting in grayscale images. The problem is the fact that these pre-processed images have pixel values higher than 255. If I save them with imwrite() as, for instance, .PNG files, does matlab normalize the values to be in [0,255] or no? should I have to save my images in another format to keep their original values?

Comment: do u mean 8 bytes per pixel??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `bitdepth` parameter to set that.

```
imwrite(img,'myimg.png','bitdepth',16)
```

Of course, not all image formats support all bitdepths, so make sure you are choosing the the right format for your data.

Comment: what if I don't now the bithdepth? is it also possible?

Comment: @mad No. You can not put a random number in the bitdepth. File formats are standarised, so while they are flexible in some parameters, you can not just put the number you want. So  a bitdeph of 15 is not possible. Check the fileformat standads to make sure it supports what you want

Comment: 2^16=65536, which means that with 16 bits you can store pixels from 0 to 65535 @mad